# How to get control text?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to get control text. but this code return parent class name.

```
const wchar_t* textInput = L"Login";   

HWND btnHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", textInput, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                 mCoordinate.x, mCoordinate.y, mDimension.cx, mDimension.cy, parentHandle, NULL, 
                 (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(parentHandle, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);

wchar_t* textOutput;
int length = GetWindowTextLengthW(btnHandle);
GetWindowText(btnHandle, textOutput, length);

MessageBox(NULL, textOutput, L"Window Text", MB_OK);
```

Comment: You must allocate the string you pass to GetWindowText https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw

Comment: @SimonMourier can u check again my code, it output empty

Comment: `textOutput` is uninitialized pointer, it can't be used. Use `if (length) { length++; textOutput = new wchar_t[length]; GetWindowText... MessageBox... delete[] textOutput;}`

Answer (score 1):

As documented, the `lpString` argument to [`GetWindowTextW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw) is:

> The buffer that will receive the text.

The API does not provide that buffer for you. Instead, you will have to pass it in, as illustrated here:

```cpp
size_t length{ GetWindowTextLengthW(btnHandle) };
// Allocates a buffer for `length` characters plus a NUL terminator
std::wstring text(length, L'\0');
// The API promises to write a NUL terminator into the final character
// so it is safe to lie about the length
length = GetWindowTextW(btnHandle, text.data(), text.size() + 1);
// Resize in case we got less than promised
text.resize(length);

MessageBoxW(NULL, text.c_str(), L"Window Text", MB_OK);
```

Comment: You don't need the +1 when constructing the `std::wstring`, since it is guaranteed to be null-terminated in C++11 and later (you are clearly using C++17 or later, where `wstring::data()` can return a non-const pointer). You can use `+1` when calling `GetWindowText()` instead, eg: `std::wstring text(length, L'\0'); GetWindowTextW(btnHandle, text.data(), length+1);` But either way, `GetWindowTextLength()` *can* return more characters than `GetWindowText()` returns, so try: `std::wstring text(length, L'\0'); length = GetWindowTextW(btnHandle, text.data(), length+1); text.resize(length);`

Comment: @rem That's true, though risky. It would require passing `text.size() + 1` as the length, so that `GetWindowText` doesn't truncate the output. And if that call happens to write anything other than a zero to the final element, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Maybe not *that* risky. The API promises to either write less than the length, or zero-terminate the output if it writes to the end. I suppose the wording in the Standard was changed to enable scenarios specifically like this one.

Comment: Are these comments in regards to [`GetWindowTextLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengtha) documentation and DBCS characters in ANSI/Unicode mixture? I thought it can be ignored in Unicode application. If `GetWindowTextLengthW` was looking at DBCS, then the reported length would be the same, or shorter. It should be only `GetWindowTextLengthA` which may report possible larger length.